# What does Middle English "bihiȝten" mean?

Tags: middle-english, paleography

What does Middle English "bihiȝten" mean?

[image]

[Wycliffe's Bible (page 87)](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/)

Mk.14:11

[Studylight:](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=*ay&search_form_type=general&q1=Mark.14%3A11&s=2&t1=en_wyc&ns=0)

"And thei herden, and ioyeden, and bihiyten to yyue hym money. And he souyt hou he schulde bitraye hym couenabli."

King James Bible:

"...And when they heard it, they were glad, and promised to give him money. And he sought how he might conveniently betray him."

Comment: Pretty sure that says _behei3ten_ (can’t type the yogh on my phone), with the e written on top of the i as was often done. Regardless, since yogh is the orthographic equivalent of _gh_, it should be rather straightforward to figure out what _beh(e)i3ten_ corresponds to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [behoten = to promise](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED4533/track)

I find that script hard to read so can't tell about how accurate the ascii is. I searched for a [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/) and then tried your text on it and it gave no results. Then I tried other things for the 'y' in 'bihiyten': 'h', 'th', 'g', and then 'gh' which finally worked.

This is plausibly cognate with modern English ['behest'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/behest).

Comment: Looks to be not just a cognate but the etymon of "behest", according to Etym Online.

Answer (score 1):

From my examination of the *Wycliffe Facsimile New Testament* published by CIY, which I think your photograph is from since it looks identical to my copy, I believe this word is the preterite plural (i.e. the same for 1st, 2nd and 3rd persons plural) from infinitive 'bihete' = to promise, which agrees with the Authorized Version that you quote.
Other forms of this word that I have noted in this MS include:

- 'biheten', *3rd person plural present*, 'promise'. E.g. 'and biheten fredom to hem' (2 Peter 2:19, A.V. 'they promise them liberty')
- 'bihighte', *3rd person singular preterite, and past participle*, 'promised'. E.g. 'which lijf god that lyeth not bihighte bifore tymes of the world' (Titus 1:2, A.V. 'which God, that cannot lie, promised before the world began');
- 'biheeste', *noun*, 'promise', e.g. 'and this is the biheeste: that he bihighte to us, everlasting lijf' (I John 2:25, A.V. 'And this is the promise that he hath promised us, even eternal life.')

For the scribe of this MS, infinitives end in -e (not -en as apparently used by other Middle Engish scribes), while -en is his verb ending for all plural persons in both present and past tenses.